# Having trouble returning a templated struct object pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm writing all the method prototypes in the class and their definitions will be outside of it. Here's my AVL class setup:

```
template <class type>
class avlTree : public binarySearchTree<type>
{
public:
    avlTree();      //default constructor
    ~avlTree();     //destructor
    const type & findMin() const;
    const type & findMax() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void printTree() const;
    void makeEmpty();
    void insert(const type & newData);
    void remove(const type & deleteItem);

private:
    template<class type>
    struct avlNode
    {
        type info;
        avlNode *left;
        avlNode *right;
        int height;

        avlNode(const type & data, avlNode *ll, avlNode *rl, int h = 0)
            : info{ data }, left{ ll }, right{ rl }, height{ h } {}
    };

    avlNode<type> * root;

    void insert(const type & newData, avlNode<type> * & p);
    void remove(const type & deleteItem, avlNode<type> * & p);
    avlNode<type>* findMin(avlNode<type> * p);  //these two methods are where I'm having problems.
    avlNode<type>* findMax(avlNode<type> * p);

};
```

I'm having trouble writing the internal (private) `findMin()` and `findMax()` definitions. To add clarity, not the actual algorithm but the syntax to return the avlNode object pointer. The prototype in the class shows no errors but when I try to write its definition outside of the class the Intellisense won't show and the local p pointer is not showing its members when I try to code `p->member`. Usually Intellsense shows that drop down menu with its members but it's not showing it. So I know there is some sort of syntax error. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the way the template is set up but I'm not sure. So what am I doing wrong?

My method definition I'm having trouble with:

```
template <class type>
typename avlTree<type>::avlNode* avlTree<type>::findMin(avlNode * p)
{
    if (p == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (p->left == nullptr)  //when I hover over 'p->left' that's when Intellisense says '<unknown> avlTree<type>::avlNode::left'
        return p;
    return findMin(p->left);  //same thing here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
template <typename type>
avlTree<type>::avlNode<type>* 
    avlTree<type>::findMin(avlNode<type>* p) {
  // ...
}
```

In case you haven't realized it yet, you don't need to make `avlNode` itself a template. You are enabling unnecessary flexibility, whereby `avlTree<int>::avlNode<long>` is a thing, but are never actually taking advantage of said flexibility. Make `avlNode` a plain non-template member class - that'll simplify matters considerably.

Comment: Ah I see. Because the avlNode struct is part of the avlTree class, you have to type `avlTree<type>::avlNode<type>*`. I was forgetting that part. Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need `typename` before the return type, as `avlNode` is a dependent type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: my comment was for when `avlNode` was fixed to be no longer "itself a template", as you put it....  See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee8777bf85592edf).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried doing what you said by not making `avlNode` a template and now the members won't show when I try `p->member`. Also, when I leave it as is (with `avlNode` a template), it won't compile and says I need a semi-colon after the first `*`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, I kind of fixed it because I was forgetting the `typename` before the return type. It compiles but now the `p->member` still won't show its drop down menu and when I hover over it, Intellisense says `<unknown> avlTree<type>::avlNode::left`. Why does it say `<unknown>`? I'll post up the definition so you can see what I mean.